# sound through both speakers and headset

Tags: windows-8.1, audio, bluetooth, speakers

I share my room with my roommate and both of us have different taste of music.
I have a Bluetooth headset, an earphone and in-built speaker in my laptop.
now i want to play song of my choice on one of the above output device and other song on anyone of rest of output device.Please tell me if it is possible and if yes, then how?

After some research I was able to play music through both speaker and headset but I am not able to play music as described above.
If anyone knows please help me.

If you need any detail regarding anything like driver or details of output device please mention in comment.I am using windows-8.1 .

Answer (score 1):

You really need two "machines" to run the different music sets. You could try a virtual Linux machine and split the output devices. If you use VMware Player, you can specify which output to use.

[image]

If you have never set up a vitual Linux, here is **[one of my tutorials](https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=475A0A48CA6D4035&id=475A0A48CA6D4035%211853)** that explains how to set up Mint.